# jQuery CSS - do not allow to override

Tags: html, css, razor

I have a page with a set of jQuery accordions built from an MVC `foreach` statement.

Before each accordion, I would like to add some text in a `<p>` tag. Whatever I have tried, the jQuery styling has added classes and styles to my tag.

Is there a simple way to add a `<p>` tag and say that I want it the same as the other `<p>` tags on the non jQuery page? Almost like an inline `!important` setting.

EDIT

Code to build accordions:

```
<section id="accordions" aria-label="accordion-expand\collapse" class="col-md-12">                    
@{
  foreach (var accordion in Model.Content.Children.Where(f => f.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("Accordion", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
  {
    var isInScheme = Model.User != null ? Model.User.IsInScheme(accordion.GetPropertyValue<String>("schemeTypes")) : false;
    var isMemberStatus = Model.User != null ? Model.User.IsMemberStatusType(accordion.GetPropertyValue<String>("memberStatusTypes")) : false;

    if ((!accordion.HasValue("schemeTypes") && !accordion.HasValue("memberStatusTypes")) || (isInScheme && isMemberStatus))
    {
      if (accordion.GetPropertyValue<String>("accordionText") != "" & accordion.GetPropertyValue<String>("accordionText") != null)
      {
        <p>accordion.GetPropertyValue<String>("accordionText")</p>                          
      }

      <h3 class="clearfix" id="@accordion.Id">
        <span class="title">@(accordion.GetPropertyValue<String>("accordionHeader"))</span>
      </h3>
      <article class="clearfix">
        @(Html.Raw(accordion.GetPropertyValue<String>("accordionContent")))
      </article>
    }
  }
}
</section>
```

where the `accordionText` is being inserted, jQuery is adding the classes to it.

Comment: Add your code & explain what exactly is the problem.

Comment: "from **an MVC**". Or has a new jQuery been released? o.O

Comment: @MA-Maddin It's just Razor syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the problem is your jQuery CSS selector.

You may have something like this:

```
$("p").addClass("class");
```

That is why jQuery is matching all your `<p>` tags, even the ones you do not want it to.

---

What you could do is change your tag selector to a class selector, then use this class in the descendant `<p>` elements of the accordion.

---

### Option 1:

Change this:

`<p>accordion.GetPropertyValue<String>("accordionText")</p>`

To this:

```
<p class="accordion-text">accordion.GetPropertyValue<String>("accordionText")</p>
```

And this:

```
$("p").addClass("class");
```

To this:

```
$(".accordion-text").addClass("class");
```

---

### Option 2:

```
$("#accordions p").addClass("class");
```